# postgresql get unique count for multiple values

Tags: sql, postgresql, count

I'm new to POSTGRESQL and am trying to get the unique count where `deleted_by is null` for multiple `comp_source_store` values: ["petsmart", "amazon", "qfc"]

I can get my number perfectly fine with one single query like so:

```
select 
    count(distinct(comp_upc)) as petsmart from matches where 
    comp_source_store='petsmart' 
    and deleted_by is null
```

Returns a response like this:

```
productMatches =  [ { petsmart: '11562' } ]
```

I am trying to eventually get my query to return a response with an int value for each `comp_source_store` like this:

```
productMatches =  [ { petsmart: '11562' }, { amazon: '231' }, { qfc: '5333' },  ]
```

I have tried to seperate my query with a comma to get two unique counts but the query will not run and results in an error pointing to the comma char:

```
          select 
          count(distinct(comp_upc)) as petsmart from matches where 
          comp_source_store='petsmart' and deleted_by is null,

          count(distinct(comp_upc)) as amazon from matches where 
          comp_source_store='amazon' and deleted_by is null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use group by to put each store on a row, like this:

```
select 
    comp_source_store,
    count(distinct(comp_upc)) as comp_upc_count
from matches 
where 
    comp_source_store in ('petsmart', 'amazon', 'qfc')
    and deleted_by is null
group by 
    comp_source_store
```

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select count(distinct comp_upc) filter (where comp_source_store = 'petsmart') as petsmart,
       count(distinct comp_upc) filter (where comp_source_store = 'amazon') as amazon,
       . . .  -- and so on
from matches
where deleted_by is null;
```

You might find it easier to put the results in rows:

```
select comp_source_store, count(distinct comp_upc) as cnt
from matches
where deleted_by is null
group by comp_source_store
```